# How to access some email, and print a specific mail's message body?

Tags: linux, email, unix

I have an email address `email_reports@coldmail.com`, on which some reports are received daily. How can I access that mail through a terminal, find a specific mail that I need (say, check the headers or the body for string `DEBUG: Daily Data Report`), and print out it's body to a file in a single piped command? I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and the standard `mail` command, as well as `mutt`. I've tried searching for such functionality online, but all I've managed to find is guides on how to set up various mail agents, but not to process emails in a script-like fashion.

Comment: [Procmail](http://www.procmail.org/) will do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://harrybailey.com/2009/02/send-or-pipe-an-email-to-a-php-script/ for an excellent article on how to pipe incoming mail to a script.  This technique can be used to pipe incoming mail to just about any kind of script, be it php, perl, python, etc.